# Extremely fast shipping time

Tags: grammar, irregular-plurals

Which sentence is grammatically correct:

> "We can provide extremely fast shipping times"

> "We can provide extremely fast shipping time"

I was arguing the first was correct because multiple items will be shipped.

Also

> "As for shipping time, your order is expected to be delivered within
> 10-20 days from the day of your order"

I was arguing with my coworker "As for shipping time" is awkward, but couldn't discern grammatically why it was incorrect.

Comment: While these are closely related, you will get better responses by asking two separate questions. Welcome to the community.

Comment: Why do you judge 10-20 days extremely fast? Three days is.

Comment: You should bear in mind that, if your readers are pedantically minded, the might object to *fast shipping time(s)* regardless of whether the singular or the plural is used. If anything is fast here, they might argue, it is the shipping, not the shipping time; if the shipping is fast, then the shipping time is short.

Answer (score 1):

The use of these two possibilities is quite flexible. In the case you are mentioning, both will do, but the construction with "time" in the plural is a little more explicit. The plural would still be proper in the case of a single item, if, according to a process of delivery that depends on the location and the distance, times vary significantly. Of course, whatever the context, additional precisions should be made available, and that would clear any possible doubt people might have.

"As for" is a standard idiom ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/as_3#as_idmg_3)).

> **as for**       used to start talking about somebody/something
> SYNONYM regarding

This idiom is used when changing subject (Robert- Collins French-English/,English-French dictionary); personally, I believe that there has to be a connection between the two subjects, as there is in the present context (questions about  shipping are bound to be customer's concern);  of course, according to these context details, the definition in OALD does not include the case when something/somebody is the first matter that is being talked about.